# How to force the text to appear after a table

Tags: tables, floats

```
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    ~                 & Horns rev 1 & Horns rev 2 & Anholt \\ \hline
    Antal møller      & 80   & 90 & 111    \\ \hline
    Effekt pr. mølle  & 2 MW   & 2.3 MW  & 3.6 MW \\ \hline
    Areal             & 20km$^2$ & 33km$^2$  & 88km$^2$      \\ \hline
    Samlede effekt    & 160MW  & 209MW & 400MW \\ \hline
    Effekt pr. areal  & 0.008 MW/m$^2$ & 0,0063 MW/m$^2$ & 0,0045 MW/m$^2$ \\ \hline
    Km kabel          & 55  & 72  & 185 \\ \hline
    kWh-pris          & 48 øre & 51.8 øre  & 105.1 øre\\ \hline
    Pris (mia. kr.)   & 2  & 3.5 & 9     \\ \hline
    Rotordiameter     & 80 meter & 93 meter  & 120 meter \\ \hline
    \setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}
        \makebox (16,40)[t]{Formation} & \raisebox{0mm}[42mm][1mm] {\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=40mm]{Horns_rev_1.png}}
    & {\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=40mm]{Horns_rev_2.png}}  &
    {\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=40mm]{Anholt.png}}  \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}

\end{table}
```

Insert text here

I can't seem to find an answer that is working for me

Comment: What text are you thinking about?

Comment: `Insert text here` <= Place the block *before* `\end{table}`

Comment: Please re-read your posting. As it currently stands, there is simply no clear way to answer your question, "How to force the text to appear after a table", because your posting provides only a table but no text. You may (or may not) be disappointed to learn that the people who tend to provide answers on this site are absolutely no good at all at divination. If you don't provide even a hint as to what the text might be, don't be surprised that nobody comes up with a decent guess as to how your issue may be solved.

Comment: note that you have used the `table` environment (and tagged the question `float`) the only reason to use a float environment is to specify that it can _float_ to a different page to help with page breaking, so by design it is the _opposite_ of forcing it to appear in some fixed position relative to some text.

Comment: Please clarify if you want the table to be forced to a specific place, or if you want to have some short annotation to the table to stick with it. It is very very important to know. If it is an annotation, do as i have written above. If you do otherwise (see answer), your report will be ugly as sh\*t.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I you absolutely, positively must ensure that a `table` is preceded by some text and followed by some other text, i.e., if you want to utterly disable LaTeX's float-placement algorithm, you could load the `float` package and use the `H` placement specifier: `\begin{table}{H}` --- as in, "I WANT IT HERE." Do be aware, though, that you're going to get exactly what you *say* you want. E.g., if the `table` won't fit in the space that's available on the current page page, a great big ugly hole will be created and the table will start on the following page.

Separately, you ought to give a lot more thought to the structure of the `tabular` material inside the `table`. As it stands, your code produces a `tabular` that's far wider than the text block, and there's considerably redundancy in the cells since, e.g., the units are repeated instead of being centralized (say, in the corresponding row header). In the following example, I've employed a `tabularx` environment, with `X` columns for columns 2 thru 4, set the widths of the graphs to `\linewidth`, and grouped the units in the descriptor column.

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx,tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage[per-mode=symbol]{siunitx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float} % for "H" placement specifier

\begin{document}
some random text before the table \dots

\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}lXXX@{}}
\toprule
 & Horns rev 1 & Horns rev 2 & Anholt \\ 
\midrule
Antal møller & 80 & 90 & 111    \\ 
Effekt pr. mølle (\si{\mega\watt})& 2 & 2.3 & 3.6 \\ 
Areal (\si{\kilo\meter\squared})  & 20 & 33 & 88 \\ 
Samlede effekt (\si{\mega\watt})  & 160  & 209 & 400 \\ 
Effekt pr.\ areal (\si{\mega\watt\per\meter\squared}) & 0.008 & 0.0063 & 0.0045 \\ 
Kabel (\si{\kilo\meter})      & 55 & 72   & 185   \\ 
Pris pr.\ kWh (øre)    & 48 & 51.8 & 105.1 \\ 
Pris (mia.\ kr.)  & 2  &  3.5 & 9     \\ 
Rotordiameter (\si{\meter}) & 80 & 93 & 120\\
\addlinespace
& \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=1.2\linewidth]{Horns_rev_1.png} 
& \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=1.2\linewidth]{Horns_rev_2.png}  
& \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=1.2\linewidth]{Anholt.png}  \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

some more random text after the table\dots
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm curious: You sound really against forcing a table's location in this way. Besides the possibility for creating a big, ugly gap, why is this? Is there a better environment/macro/command for such tables? Perhaps in such circumstances, the `tabular` environment should be used by itself without the `table` environment, since there might (?) be no need for a caption in such instances.

Comment: @jvriesem - Not creating a big, ugly gap at the bottom of a page should be a pretty good reason for not using the `H` placement specifier, right? :-) On the other hand, if you have a simple and fairly short `tabular` environment and no need for a numbered caption, such a `tabular` environment should likely be placed rather close to the place in the text where it's referred to.